# WorkFusion RPA Express SetCellValue task fail

Tags: excel, variables, rpa, workfusion

I'm trying to create a workflow using WorkFusion RPA Express. I've copied a value to a variable from an excel sheet using (Ctrl+C) and when I try to 'set cell value' using the same variable in another excel sheet, it gives an error.

Please help me resolve this.

[Workflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXFSX.png)

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: Execution Failure. 'Error executing SetCellValueAction'.

Comment: Try to use caps A1.

Comment: @VishalBareja Use of caps didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the version of RPA Express used. Update to the latest version solved the issue.